# Storing a trial duration in years, months, days, hours in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

**UPDATE:** Just to be clear for future viewers, the accepted answer does not propose a different or better approach to those given in this question (it uses a "total number of days" (or hours) column). From the discussion in the comments, after the initial confusion, it resulted that there's likely no way to cover both ease of use and precision, so using a single but inexact column in "days" was the approach we went with, and the accepted answer represents that. Cheers!

---

Our products have licenses, and those licenses might be trials, having an end time starting from the point when they are first used. The trial period consists of a certain number of years, months, days and, ideally, hours as well.

We wanted to store this period in an SQL Server database, but are struggling. There doesn't seem to be a data type for this, based on [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql).

- DateTimeOffset is not a real "offset" but a date AND its offset from UTC (please correct me if I'm wrong), so it doesn't seem to support concepts like "0 months".
- Storing a "total number of seconds" or "total number of hours" is susceptible to time changes around the globe. It is also hard to look at a value (as a human) and have a notion of how long the trial is.
- Other alternatives, such as storing a string "1y2m15d5h" (1 year, 2 months, 15 days and 5 hours. Extreme example) would render queries impossible, such as searching for all trials with duration longer than 1 year (there might even be some specified as 14m, which is also more than a year).

Possible solutions are:

1. Adding 4 columns just for this (years, months, days, hours). It would make queries much more complex than we wanted.
2. Forgetting support for durations in hours (probably a very uncommon case) and using "total number of days" instead. Unfortunately, this can't accurately represent a year, because of leap years (365 days might not be a full year).

Do you have other possible solutions for this? A readable, easily queryable format for a time/date offset? We couldn't find a concrete answer after searching the web.

Comment: why make it so complicated? work out the expiry date when it's first used and store it as a datetime. You'll thank me for this later or look back at this comment and think, why didn't i listen to that guy.

Comment: Why not just store a start date and an end date for the trial? EDIT: Tanner beat me to it

Comment: Because trials have different durations and should be counted from the time they are first used. We can't store the expiry date when it's first used if we don't have the duration for it! :)

Please tell me how I can make the question clearer if it wasn't.

Comment: In fact we already store the expiry date AFTER it is calculated from the trial duration added to the current time. The issue is storing that interval.

Comment: On first use connect to server, store expiry. I don't see the problem with the obvious solution already presented!

Comment: People, we can't store the expiry date if we don't know the trial duration!

Comment: @CanisLupus, but isn't  your question about how you can store the trial duration? How can you store the trial duration if you don't know the trial duration? I actually get your point though. Years, Months, Days, hours is the best way I can see to store this.

Comment: OK. When we add a trial license to the database, we specify a duration for it. It is useful for promotions and review licenses, etc. For fairness, the period starts from first insertion. The only thing that's stored in the database before first insertion is the duration, hence the whole problem. Afterwards we add the duration to the current date and use the expiry date as normal.

Comment: @CanisLupus store your trial duration in in a single unit, i.e. hours, if you want to go down to that level, otherwise store it in days. Don't store, Years, months, days.... etc. it will make all calculations around it more complicated. So you would say 1 year (@365 days) = 24*365 = 8760 hours (expiry duration) then add that to the start day: `dateadd(hour,24*365,getdate())`

Comment: Thank you Tanner, but that is already one of the proposed solutions in the question. Unfortunately, it is not readable for a human, and is susceptible to time changes, like mentioned.

Comment: Databases are not designed to be "readable for a human" - thats what user interfaces are for! Just store your duration like any datetime is - periods from datum. Probably hours is as granular as you ever need.

Comment: Yes, we have a simple database. That's a fair point, although there's still the issue with time accuracy. How do we represent a trial for one month in days? 30 days? What about months with 31 days? 28?

Comment: The real question is what is more important to you, accuracy or simplicity. Does it bother you if a trial increases or decreases in length due to known variations (Daylight saving, varying month lengths, leap years). If it does then you have to store the individual units, and do more complicated calculations, if it doesn't bother you then you can just use a single unit and if you really need it to be readable by humans (which should not really be a consideration for how you store something), then do as Tanner said, and create a view.

Comment: Do you have a few "standard" licenses - like 1 month, 1 year etc? or is it truly ad hoc?

Comment: Can you not use three DateTime columns - TrialStartDate, TrialEndDate, TrialPeriod . TrialPeriod being a datetime since Jan 1st 1900 as the length of trial. You could then use datediff to find length of trial in days, months etc.

Comment: @GarethD That is indeed the trade-off we were seeing. We wanted to know if there were better solutions for the problem that we were not seeing. If there aren't, we'll likely manage it in days.

Comment: @Jamiec We don't have standard licenses, although sure, there will be some more common than others. It can't be an enum-like field, unfortunately.

Comment: @SteveFord Unfortunately, 1900 would have to have the same structure as whichever year or years the trial is for, otherwise it's the same as specifying 365 days for a year (problems with leap years, for example). I thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Human scale time periods are just plain nasty, with their variable lengths. You have to work out what trade offs are acceptable to *you* (and your organization) before trying to work with them. E.g. you either decide that "1 month = 30 days always" or you accept that someone starting a 1 month trial in February gets a worse deal then someone starting a 1 month trial in July. These aren't *technical* problems to solve, they're business issues.

Comment: I see, @Damien_The_Unbeliever. That's the unfortunate conclusion we are coming to while reading your comments. :)

Thanks to everyone for your suggestions. We'll work it out one way or another, unless a better approach comes along (seems unlikely now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by myself and others in the comments, simplify the duration values so that you store it either in hours or days, ignore the longer months and leap years for the sake of simplicity.

This solution stores duration in days, to keep it simple for your queries for the UI and has a computed value for hours to be used in the calculation of the end date, *although you may not need both columns*, I'm just presenting them as an option:

```
CREATE TABLE #trials
(
    Customer NVARCHAR(20),
    StartTime DATETIME,
    TrialDays INT,
    TrialHours AS(TrialDays*24),
    EndTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #trials
(
    Customer,
    StartTime,
    TrialDays,
    EndTime
)
VALUES
(   N'Bob', GETDATE(), 1, NULL), -- 1 day
(   N'Dave', GETDATE(), 7, NULL), -- 7 days
(   N'Jon', GETDATE(), 30, NULL), -- 30 days
(   N'Tom', GETDATE(), 90, NULL), -- 90 days
(   N'Jim', GETDATE(), 365, NULL) -- 365 days (approximation of a year)

SELECT * FROM #trials AS t

UPDATE #trials
SET EndTime = DATEADD(HOUR, TrialHours, StartTime)

SELECT * FROM #trials AS t

DROP TABLE #trials
```

Produces:

```
Customer    StartTime               TrialDays   TrialHours  EndTime
Bob         2017-09-11 10:50:30.940 1           24          2017-09-12 10:50:30.940
Dave        2017-09-11 10:50:30.940 7           168         2017-09-18 10:50:30.940
Jon         2017-09-11 10:50:30.940 30          720         2017-10-11 10:50:30.940
Tom         2017-09-11 10:50:30.940 90          2160        2017-12-10 10:50:30.940
Jim         2017-09-11 10:50:30.940 365         8760        2018-09-11 10:50:30.940
```

Comment: Just to be clear for future viewers, I'll accept this answer even though it does not solve our original problem (in fact, using a "total number of days" (or hours) column is a suggestion that comes in the question text itself). From the discussion in the comments, after the initial confusion, it resulted that there's likely no way to cover both ease of use and precision, so using a single but inexact column in "days" was the approach we went with, and this answer represents that. Thanks to everyone for their contribution.

Answer (score 0):

I am saving year, month , day and hrs in xml columns and calculating expire date by retrieving data from this xml column-

```
create table temp (
     ID int      , Duration xml   , StartDate datetime  
)
go

insert into temp
select 1 ,'<Time><Yr>1</Yr><Mo>2</Mo><Dy>3</Dy><Hr>4</Hr></Time>' , getdate() 
union all select 2 ,'<Time><Yr>2</Yr><Mo>2</Mo><Dy>3</Dy><Hr>3</Hr></Time>', getdate() 
union all select 3 , '<Time><Yr>1</Yr><Mo>7</Mo><Dy>6</Dy><Hr>9</Hr></Time>', getdate() 
union all select 3 , '<Time><Yr>0</Yr><Mo>11</Mo><Dy>22</Dy><Hr>15</Hr></Time>' , getdate() 


SELECT  ID , StartDate , 
 t1.Duration.value('(/Time/Yr)[1]','int')YR ,  
t1.Duration.value('(/Time/Mo)[1]','int')MO,  
t1.Duration.value('(/Time/Dy)[1]','int')DY ,   
t1.Duration.value('(/Time/Hr)[1]','int')HR ,
dateadd( HOUR , t1.Duration.value('(/Time/Hr)[1]','int'), dateadd( day ,t1.Duration.value('(/Time/Dy)[1]','int') ,dateadd(MONTH ,t1.Duration.value('(/Time/Mo)[1]','int')  ,  dateadd(year, t1.Duration.value('(/Time/Yr)[1]','int') , StartDate) ))) as EndTime
FROM temp t1
```

Comment: Your own example illustrates the downfall in this approach. The values you have used indicate a trial period of 1 year, 2 months, 9 days and 5 hours, but as of running today, we get a start time of 2017-09-11 and an end date of 2018-11-18, a time period of 1 year 2 months and 7 days. All the same problems of varying month and year lengths crop up here, the only difference is you have chosen a more convoluted and obscure way to store the length of the trial by using arbitrary dates after 1900.

Comment: GarethD is unfortunately correct. This approach also doesn't support having an offset of just one year, for example, since months and days have to have at least 1 in their value. And I believe smalldatetime is deprecated or at least not recommended for new projects.

Comment: Sorry guys , i posted my answer without proper analysis. However i think we can do this by using XML data type. I have updated my answer please review :)